# Linux: Text editor that supports windows cp1256 and iso 88859-6 encodings

Tags: gratis, linux, text-editor

I am looking for a gratis editor that works on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit that can read Arabic encodings, specifically cp1256 and iso 88859-6.

I want also the ability to save/convert them to different encoding such as utf8. I have Gvim, Libreoffice and sublime text 3 installed, if there are plugins to those editors that would do the job, it's great.

I am not that good with vim/emacs so unless there's no other solutions, lets stay away from them, otherwise, I'll try to learn them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gedit](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gedit/), which Ubuntu ships by default, lets you select the encoding of your file.

[image]

Another option could be to convert your files prior to editing, i.e. using [iconv](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/linux/iconv.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The text editor [**Geany**](http://www.geany.org/) (cross-platform and FLOSS) should be able to do this.

It’s included in Ubuntu’s packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/geany

Here’s a (German) screenshot of the menu where you can select the character encoding, showing the two required options for Arabic text, [ISO 8859-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-6) and [Windows-1256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256):

[image]

Conversion of character sets is supported, as [described in the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#character-sets-and-unicode-byte-order-mark-bom):

> Geany provides support for detecting and converting character sets. So you can open and save files in different character sets, and even convert a file from one character set to another. To do this, Geany uses the character conversion capabilities of the GLib library.

You’ll have to save/reload the file after selecting a different encoding. In the <kbd>File</kbd> menu there is also an option to directly reload the opened document with a different encoding.

Comment: just tried to do it, from geany preferences right? didn't work,  can you get it to show the arabic letters? here https://www.sendspace.com/file/2hbaye

Comment: @Fischer: This file seems to display fine with WINDOWS-1256 (`File` → `Reload as`). However, saving it (after changing encoding in `Document` → `Character encoding`) is not possible because this example document seems to contain invalid characters. Workaround: Display it as WINDOWS-1256 (via `File` menu), then change encoding (via `Document` menu) to UTF-8, then save it.